# Javassist Classpool.get() does not find class when using fully qualified name

Tags: javassist

I am attempting to get a simple Javassist example going. Consider the following code. Assume variable classPath points to a correct class folder that contains the required .class file.

When running, the first invocation of classPool.get() succeeds and the second fails. The spec of method ClassPool.get() requires a fully-qualified class name. **Why is that?**

```java
package com.domain.jcp;

import javassist.ClassPool;
import javassist.CtClass;
import javassist.NotFoundException;

public class Jcp  {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws NotFoundException {
        ClassPool classPool = ClassPool.getDefault();
        String classPath = "[CORRECT PATH TRUNK]\\target\\test-classes\\com\\domain\\jcp";
        classPool.insertClassPath(classPath);
        CtClass clazz1 = classPool.get("JcpTest");
        CtClass clazz2 = classPool.get("com.domain.jcp.JcpTest");
    }
}
```

The folder layout is a standard layout for a Maven project.

Comment: Please give your questions some more love in the future and do not post broken code. The code you posted here would not even compile when replacing `[CORRECT PATH TRUNK]` by an actual path. For example, you posted a `catch` without a `try`. I fixed that for you, removing the superfluous catch block, simply declaring the exception on the method instead. For this simple example, that is enough. BTW, you also printed the exception message and stack trace manually instead of simply using `ex.printStackTrace()`, which contains both already. I also added the missing imports.

Comment: @kriegaex Thanks for your answer it did hit the nail on its head. I think the gist of the problem was the broader question of "How do classpaths work in Java?". I believe you understood the issue without compiling and running the code.  In general, I don't think compilable code is a prerequisite to asking a question unless it is warranted by the depth of the question. A code sketch is more than sufficient information for a precise, punchy answer, like yours in the right contexts and I believe this was. We all have a limited amount of time and at some point pedantry just gets in the way.

Comment: @kriegaex But sorry about the copy-pasta, indeed I hadn't noticed I missed some lines. I had some issues with the editor, going back and forth I've missed some things. I'll do better in the future.

Comment: I am part of a community of people who like to help each other for free in their sparetime. But most of us have daytime jobs, too. So if you are asking anyone for help - not just here on SO, but in any situation in this life - make it as easy as possible for them to help you, especially if they are not obliged to you in any way but volunteers. Respect their time budgets. With regard to your own precious time, it saves you time to post a reproducible example, because you get answers more quickly. BTW, doesn't editing a class take longer than just posting it completely?

Comment: @kriegaex I agree with you in spirit. In this particular case I made an error in editing. But what I was telling you is that in some cases matters, in some it does not and it is counterproductive to be pedantic. I do appreciate the time invested in your answer and your example and I commit to doing better in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You simply need to use the correct classpath. This is wrong, because you are pointing into a package subdirectory rather than straight to the root:

```java
String classPath = "[CORRECT PATH TRUNK]\\target\\test-classes\\com\\domain\\jcp";
```

This is correct:

```java
String classPath = "[CORRECT PATH TRUNK]\\target\\test-classes";
```

Then you need to use the fully qualified package name, i.e. of these

```java
CtClass clazz1 = classPool.get("JcpTest");
CtClass clazz2 = classPool.get("com.domain.jcp.JcpTest");
```

only the latter is correct, while the former is not.

---

**Update:** Here is what happens if you misunderstand what a Java classpath is:

```java
import javassist.ClassPool;
import javassist.CtClass;
import javassist.NotFoundException;

public class JavassistGetClass {
  private static final String BASE_PATH = "...";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws NotFoundException {
    ClassPool classPool = ClassPool.getDefault();

    // How to correctly use a classpath in Javassist
    String classPath = BASE_PATH + "\\target\\classes";
    classPool.insertClassPath(classPath);
    CtClass ctClass = classPool.get("de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q70786275.Application");
    System.out.println("Correct package name: " + ctClass.getPackageName());

    // How NOT to use a classpath in Javassist (or anywhere else)
    String classPathIncorrect = BASE_PATH + "\\target\\classes\\de\\scrum_master\\stackoverflow\\q70786275";
    classPool.insertClassPath(classPathIncorrect);
    CtClass ctClassIncorrect = classPool.get("Application");
    System.out.println("Incorrect package name: " + ctClassIncorrect.getPackageName());
  }
}
```

Console log:

```
Correct package name: de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q70786275
Incorrect package name: null
```

Comment: Please note my update with a little demonstration of why a bogus classpath pointing into a package subdirectory would lead to inconsistencies later, despite the initial `classPool.get("UnqualifiedClassName")` not throwing any exceptions.